# Erroneous roll angle estimation using EKF

Tags: python-3.x, python-ahrs

I am trying to get roll angles using Mayitzin/ahrs EKF implementation with gyroscope and acceleration data, but it is nowhere near to what the expected should be. This is how I've tried to use it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ahrs.filters import EKF
from ahrs.common.orientation import acc2q
from ahrs.common.orientation import q_correct 

#specify path to excel file
excel_file_path = r'C:\Users\aleppon\Desktop\Work\Book1.xlsx'
excel_output_path = r'C:\Users\aleppon\Desktop\Work\EKF_Q.xlsx'

#read the excel file in a dataframe
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File not Found: {excel_file_path}")
    exit()

#to access data from a data frame (use the same name as the column name given
raw_acc = df[['ACCEL_X', 'ACCEL_Y', 'ACCEL_Z']].values
raw_gyro = df[['ROLL_RATE', 'PITCH_RATE', 'YAW_RATE']].values
print('Reading done')
    

#Initialise the filter

ekf = EKF(gyr=raw_gyro, acc=raw_acc ,frequency=1628 , noises=[0.9**2, 0.2**2, 0.5**2])
ekf.Q.shape
(315453, 4)

#dataframe to store data
df = pd.DataFrame(ekf.Q)

#add custom index
custom_index = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3']
df.columns = custom_index
df.to_excel(excel_output_path)

print("Done logging, check it")
```

Now when I convert these quaternions using  **q2rpy** from **ahrs.common.orientation** using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ahrs.common.orientation import q2rpy
     
excel_input_path = r'C:\Users\aleppon\Desktop\Work\EKF_Q.xlsx'
excel_output_path = r'C:\Users\aleppon\Desktop\Work\EKF_Q2A.xlsx'

#Make a dataframe
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_input_path)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File not found: {excel_input_path}")
    exit()

#Make a df object having values form each column
Quatn = df[['q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3']].values
print("Reading Done")

num_samples = 315452
A = np.zeros((num_samples,3))
for t in range(num_samples):
    A[t] = q2rpy(Quatn[t], True)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
df.to_excel(excel_output_path, index=False)
#logger(A)
print("Done Logging, check the file")
```

I get roll angles which range from -178 to 178 degrees, and look like a noisy mess. It's only human to not get the correct plot, but even the trend in roll angle does not follow the expected outcome. What is it that I'm doing wrong here? I suspect direct quaternion to Euler angle conversion to be the issue, but I might be wrong.